# How to pass / in url query string

Tags: javascript, url, react-router, next.js

I have url like below that I am passing in the query string

URL = canada/ontario/shop6

When I access this param that I passed in the query string it discards all the data after first / and gives me just canada as result.

How can I pass the query string with all the / (slashes)?

Comment: How about passing `'URL=canada/ontario/shop6'` to [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)?

Comment: nope it converts / into %2 which I don't want

Comment: I want to pass / as it is

Comment: `%2F` should be equivalent to `/` in the query string. If it's not, then your server is not compliant with the HTTP spec.

Comment: @Demon37 Unfornately I think you can't directly pass a slash in a query string. But you can decode `%2` back to `/` by `decodeURIComponent`. Let me know why you don't want to encode/decode a slash?

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely want to pass it through the querystring, you have to encode it with encodeURIComponent and then decode it with decodeURIComponent